# React Three Preload Canvas

Tags: reactjs, three.js, preload, react-three-fiber

I have a software that uses Chromium internally to display ui elements. So I have a big SPA in react for the whole ui. There I use react-three-fiber to show some 3D animations in background of menus for example.

The problem now: Whenever I switch from one ui element to another (State change -> React component un-/mount) the 3D animation might change or dis-/appear. It always takes about a few seconds to load the animation while the rest of the page is already loaded.

How can I "preload" the react-three-fiber canvas elements so the user won't have these loading times between "route switches"? Only solution that comes to my mind is to preserve the canvas somehow and reuse it everywhere. But that sounds like an ugly way to work around react. Isn't there a **good** solution?

Answer (score 2):

I found a clean solution by myself with **react-reverse-portal**. It uses the 'portals' that came with React 16 to keep the three canvas component mounted all the time and share it between the components that use it.